# Using SeekBarPreference

Tags: android, seekbarpreference

What's the deal with SeekBarPreference?  Let me expand...

If I put a SeekBarPreference in my PreferenceScreen xml, it *works* fine (I can run it on phone and emulator), but Android Studio reports `Element SeekBarPreference is not allowed here.  Simple XML which shows this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<SeekBarPreference
    android:key="fontSize"
    android:title="@string/fontSize_title"
    android:summary="@string/fontSize_summary"
    android:max="12"
    android:defaultValue="4" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

If I try to extend SeekBarPreference (which is what I really want to do), Android Studio `Cannot resolve symbol SeekBarPreference` both at the `import` and at the `extends`.  Simple Java file to show this:

```
import android.preference.SeekBarPreference;

public class FontSizePreference extends SeekBarPreference {}
```

(Also happens if I just use `SeekBarPreference sbp;` in code.)

The source code for SeekBarPreference is in `/Sdk/sources/android-22/android/preference`, just like EditTextPreference.  I don't see anything special about it.

I can't find any documentation at developer.android.com about it, though.

What nugget of information am I missing?  What's special about this compared with, say, EditTextPreference, which I can include in XMLs and extend and use in code without problems?

Comment: *I don't see anything special about it.* - You've missed the @hide annotation which will remove it from the javadocs. That class is not part/intended for public use, so although is there you shouldn't be using it.

Comment: Thanks!  Absolutely correct. Doh!

Comment: @Luksprog why shuoldn't we use it if it's there? Is this something where the implementation details may not be "stable" and later changes could break compatibility?

Comment: The question is a bit old and the SeekBarPreference is now available both in the sdk and the preference compatibility library, so you can use it. As that class had the @hide annotations it meant it shouldn't had been considered as public API at that point. Accessing private APIs isn't recommended because you'll have a  fragile implementation subjected to break very easily whenever the developers of the SDK modify the class or remove it altogether.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and this worked for me:

instead of using:

```
<PreferenceScreen/>
```

Try using:

```
<android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen/>
```

It worked like a charm.
It simply implies that all this works best when using support libraries.
So, in your Custom seekbar you may need to import:

```
android.support.v7.preference.SeekBarPreference
```